# Why do my Gradle tests run repeatedly?

Tags: gradle

I have a pretty standard Gradle build that's building a Java project.

When I run it for the first time, it compiles everything and runs the tests. When I run it a second time without changing any files, it runs the tests again.

According to [this thread](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/how-does-gradle-decide-when-to-run-tests-td3314172.html), Gradle is supposed to be lazy by defaut and not bother running tests if nothing has changed. Has the default behaviour here been changed?

EDIT:

If I run `gradle test` repeatedly, the tests only run the first time and are subsequently skipped. However, if I run `gradle build` repeatedly, the tests get re-run every time, even though all other tasks are marked as up-to-date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I got the answer thanks to [Rene prompting me to look at the '-i' output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12639910/589259).

I actually have 2 test tasks: the 'test' one from the Java plugin, and my own 'integrationTest' one. I didn't mention this in the question because I didn't think it was relevant.

It turns out that these tasks are writing their output (reports, etc.) to the same directory, so Gradle's task-based input and output tracking was thinking that something had changed, and re-running the tests.

So the [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12675080/589259) is how to cleanly - and with minimal Groovy/Gradle code - separate two instances of the test task.

Answer (score 3):

The `gradle uptodate` check logs on info level why a task is not considered to be up-to-date. please rerun the `gradle build -i` to run with info logging at check the logging output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create test tasks in your build.gradle and then call those specific tasks to run a specific set of tests.  Here is an example that will filter out classes so that they don't get run twice (such as when running a suite and then re-running its child classes independently):

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jvmArgs '-Xms128m', '-Xmx1024m', '-XX:MaxPermSize=128m'
    maxParallelForks = 4  // this runs tests parallel if more than one class
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat "full"
        events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
        displayGranularity = 0
    }   
}
task runAllTests(type: Test) {
    include '**/AllTests.class'
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/AllTests")
    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/AllTests")
}
task runSkipSuite(type: Test) {
    include '**/Test*.class'
    testReportDir = file("${reporting.baseDir}/Tests")
    testResultsDir = file("${buildDir}/test-results/Tests")
}
```

Also, concerning your build question.  The "build" task includes a clean step which is cleaning tests from your build directory.  Otherwise the execution thinks the tests have already been ran.