# How to cleanly separate two instances of the Test task in a Gradle build

Tags: gradle

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638514/why-do-my-gradle-tests-run-repeatedly/12674403#12674403).

If I have a build with two instances of the `Test` task, what is the best (cleanest, least code, most robust) way to completely separate those two tasks so that their outputs don't overlap?

I've tried setting their `testResultsDir` and `testReportsDir` properties, but that didn't seem to work as expected. (That is, the output got written to separate directories, but still the two tasks re-ran their respective tests with each run.)

Comment: can you share your buildscript? normally, seperated testresultdir and testreportdir should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet again, Rene has pointed me in the right direction. Thank you, Rene.

It turns out that this approach does work, but I must have been doing something wrong.

For reference, I added the following to my build after all the `Test` tasks had been defined:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    testReportDir = new File("${reportsDir}/${testReportDirName}/${name}")
    testResultsDir = new File("${buildDir}/${testResultsDirName}/${name}")
}
```

This will cause all instances of the `Test` task to be isolated from each other by having their task name as part of their directory hierarchy.

However, I still feel that this is a bit evil and there must be a cleaner way of achieving this that I haven't yet found!

Answer (score 6):

**Update for the current situation as of gradle 1.8:** The testReportDir and reportsDir properties in dty's answer are deprecated since gradle 1.3. Test results are now separated automatically in the "test-results" directory and to set different destination directories for the HTML reports, call

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    reports.html.destination = file("${reporting.baseDir}/${name}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ingo Kegel's answer doesn't address the results directory, only the reports directory. Which means that a test report for a particular test type could be built that includes more test results than just that type. This can be addressed by setting the results directory as well.

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    reports.html.destination = file("${reporting.baseDir}/${name}")
    reports.junitXml.destination = file("${testResultsDir}/${name}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an update. The `reports.html.destination` way is deprecated.

This is the "new" way (Gradle > 4.x):

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
  reports.html.setDestination file("${reporting.baseDir}/${name}")
}
```